# How to assign array output to Logic app variable?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have Logic app inside that I'm calling Function App which is giving following output -

```
{
    "list1": ["111-11"],
    "list2": ["222-11"],
    "list3": ["333-11","333-131"]
}
```

Now in the Logic App i'm have taken a `3 array variables` and I want to assign above Function App output to those variables.

I tried with expression like this -

```
body('GetDataCustomerFunction')?['list1']
```

but getting below error -

> Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each'
>   at line '1' and column '3362': 'The template language expression
>   'body('GetDataCustomerFunction')?['list1']' cannot be evaluated
>   because property 'instance002List' cannot be selected. Property
>   selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.

Is that i'm missing something.?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see the error is

> Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.

can you change [`header`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint) "Content-Type" needs to be specified as **"application/json"**

Comment: header where ? i'm using simple variable to assign output from FA . updated question with screenshot. It should work dont know whats wrong :(

Comment: when you call that htpp request

Comment: I'm executing direct function app as a action

Comment: can you add the pipeline image

Comment: I resolved the issue using parse json you are pointing right need to convert it into json i thought it will automatically taken it as a json as i have return it as json :)

Comment: great that it helped